# How to print a value in a struct pointer pointed for other struct?

Tags: c

Considering that i have two structs, where one point to other, how could i print a vallue from the second struct, caliing the first?

A brief explanation of the program bellow:

NODE, a struct that points to itselft to make a pile and to a generic pointer
ALUNO, the struct that the generic pointer in NODE will point to
createNode, function that allocates memory for the nodes
preencherNode, fills the pointer of node with the respective ALUNO
pushNode, creates a new node, pointing to the last created one, making a pile
criarAluno, allocates memory for ALUNO and fills it camps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    float media;
} ALUNO;

typedef struct node
{
    void *pointer;
    struct node* link;
} NODE;

NODE* createNode(void)
{
    NODE* topo;
    topo=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    topo->pointer = NULL;
    topo->link = NULL;
    return(topo);
}

NODE* pushNode (NODE* topo)
{
    NODE* novo;
    novo=createNode();

    novo->link=topo;
    topo = novo;

    return(topo);
}

NODE* preencherNode (NODE* topo, ALUNO* data)
{
    topo->pointer=data;
    return(topo);
}

ALUNO* criarAluno(FILE* v)
{
    ALUNO* aln;
    aln=(ALUNO*)malloc(sizeof(ALUNO));

    int x;
    float y1,y2;
    fscanf (v, "%d %f %f",&x,&y1,&y2);

    aln->id=x;
    y1=(y1+y2)/2;
    aln->media=y1;

    return(aln);
}

void printData (NODE* topo)
{
    NODE* aux;
    aux=topo;

    ALUNO* aln;

    while(aux->link!=NULL)
    {
        aln=((ALUNO*)(aux->link));

        printf("ID: %d \n",aln->id);
        printf("Media: %f \n",aln->media);
        printf("........................ \n");

        aux=aux->link;
    }
}

void main ()
{
    FILE *doc;
    doc = fopen("documento.txt","r");
    if (doc==NULL){
        printf("Nao ha como abrir o arquivo");
        return(-1);
    }
    NODE *pilha;
    pilha=createNode();

    ALUNO* aluno;
    int x;

    for(x=0;x<11;x++)
    {
        aluno=criarAluno(doc);
        pilha=preencherNode(pilha,aluno);
        pilha=pushNode(pilha);
    }

    printData(pilha);
}
```

So now, the function printData, is printing the allocated space memory of the value i want, but not the value.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Show the additional code that illustrates how you are using these two structs.

Comment: If node->pointer is really a pointer to an ALUNO, then you can cast it. int id  = ((ALUNO *)node->pointer)->id; printf("%d", id);

Comment: I added a more complete version for greater compreension.

Answer (score 1):

Given as stated in question that you have NODE *node....

```
ALUNO *aluno;
aluno = (ALUNO *)(node->pointer)
printf("%d", aluno->id)
```

Comment: It's printing the allocated address, not the value.

Comment: I think you’re code is using link instead of pointer in the print routine now!